# Copy unique files to new directory?

Tags: shell-script, file-copy, duplicate-files

I have a number of folders with my various media (e.g. photos, music) from different points in time. The different folders have some of the same content (e.g. a photo might be in 2 folders), but should be mostly unique. There are no guarantees on the filename in different folders - e.g. a photo might be present as `A/foo.png` and `B/bar.png`. Alternatively, `A/baz.png` and `B/baz.png` might not be the same file.

I'm looking for some way to consolidate all of the media into a single, flat folder, with duplicates removed. Ideally, some tracking of where the files originally came from would be nice (e.g. knowing that `output/001.png` came from `A/baz.png`, etc), but this isn't strictly necessary. There are a lot (1M+ files), so the faster the better :).

I originally tried to just copy all of the files from the folders into a new folder, but this took a long time, and would only deduplicate if the filenames are identical, which isn't true in this case. I think there might be some way to get this command to go faster with `xargs -P` but I wasn't sure how.

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} \;
```

A two stage system or similar is fine - e.g. first flatten and rename all of the files into a new folder so that they all have unique filenames, and then filter out duplicates. I have the storage space to do that, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Doing it the other way around word probably be better, use `fdupes` to find and delete the duplicates, then move everything to a single directory while taking care of filename collisions.

Comment: Or `jdupes`, it seems faster than `fdupes`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made a copy of all of my data and am working through deduplicating it now with `jdupes`: `jdupes copy -Z -r -d`. Might rerun with `jdupes copy -Z -r -d -N` if it turns out there's too many duplicates to go through by hand.

Do you have suggestions for how to copy / rename all of the files to a new folder? I could write a quick python script to do it but maybe there's a better / faster option.